# Confidence Interval for Difference in Proportions - Mistake in Question?

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, proportion

Question #3 of University of Michigan's Data Science Statistics Sample Questions:

[image: Question 3]

Applying the formula is straightforward, but it seems that the note at the end of the question is wrong.  p1 seems close enough (261/501~=.52), but p2 should be 123/252=.48, not .35, which can only come from 129/(240+129) as far as I can tell.  P-hat also seems wrong - if it's supposed to refer to p1-p2, then it should be (261/501)-123/252=.0328, not .0338.

Can someone confirm whether they agree that the note at the end of the question is incorrect, or at least misleading?

https://www.si.umich.edu/sites/default/files/Sample%20of%20UMSI%20MADS%20Python%20and%20Statistics%20Assessments.pdf

Comment: Sure looks like it to me.

Comment: (+1) What an awful sample question! Not only is it riddled with typographical errors, it's too vague to be answerable.  (What parameter is the CI intended for: an odds ratio? A difference of proportions? Each of the proportions separately?)  It also suggests a bad practice of computing (and even believing in) confidence intervals in the face of nonresponses.  (In fairness, the question that follows this one provides some clarifying information.)